# How to test the following contract

Tags: solidity, unittesting, contract-verification

I read a research paper for verification and validation of solidity code
Here's [a link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~aseem/solidetherplas.pdf):)!

The code is given below:

```
contract MyBank {
   mapping (address)uint) balances;

function Deposit() {
   balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}

function Withdraw(uint amount) {
   if(balances[msg.sender]  amount) {
     msg.sender.send(amount);
     balances[msg.sender] = amount;
   }
}

function Balance() constant returns(uint) {
   return balances[msg.sender];
}
}
```

It uses F* (F-star). However, it has to convert the solidity code into F-star. I cant find the converter. Can some body please guide me how to manually test the code?

The conversion of code into F* is given below:

```
 module MyBank
 open Solidity
 type state = { balances: mapping address uint; }
 val store : state = {balances = ref empty_map}

 let deposit () : Eth unit =
    update_map store.balances msg.sender
       (add (lookup store.balances msg.sender) msg.value)

 let withdraw (amount:uint) : Eth unit =
 if (ge (lookup store.balances msg.sender) amount) then
 send msg.sender amount;
 update_map store.balances msg.sender
 (sub (lookup store.balances msg.sender) amount)

 let balance () : Eth uint =
 lookup store.balances msg.sender
```

What I understand is that:
Initially balance is zero. Then store some value in the balance using msg.value : lets suppose 500. & in lets suppose Withdraw(700) it checks that balance is greater than amount so it sends the amount & deducts balance which seems fine. However paper says:

> Using the effect system of F*, we now show how to detect some
>   vulnerable patterns such as unchecked send results in translated
>   contracts. The base construction is a combined exception and state
>   monad (see [9] for details) with the following signature:
>
> EST (a:Type) = h0:heap // input heap
>   ->send_failed:bool // send failure flag
>   ->Tot (option (a * heap) // result and new heap, or exception
>   * bool) // new failure flag
>
> return (a:Type) (x:a) : EST a = 
>   fun h0 b0->Some (x, h0), b0
>
> bind (a:Type) (b:Type) (f:EST a) (g:a->EST b) : EST b = 
>   fun h0 b0->
>   match f h0 b0 with 
>   | None, b1->None, b1 // exception in f: no output heap
>   |Some (x, h1), b1->g x h1 b1 // run g, carry failure flag

Some body please guide me how to detect the error and what the above paragraph says.

Zulfi.

Comment: To start with, the `Deposit` is not `payable` so the function can't receive Ether - it will throw an error if you try to send Ether to it.

Comment: With all due respect to the research linked, did your try first writing tests to your contract the current "usual" way, like using Truffle and JS? https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks. We have to add payable modifier to receive ether. I tried with Truffle but got some error with migrate. I would try it again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by manual testing. You could paste the contract into Remix for superficial testing. http://remix.ethereum.org. That would help you discover that the `deposit()` function doesn't accept deposits.

It might *not* help you discover that the contract contains an anti-pattern and a re-entrance vulnerability because a state-change takes place after flow control is relinquished to an untrusted contract with `transfer`.

Truffle framework provides a mocha-based unit test framework. This supports testing to the extent that the test designer wishes to explore unintended uses to make sure the contract doesn't do anything it's not supposed to do. As you know, it does not formally assure that no defect can exist.

You may be interested in adding `assert()` functions to use with something like https://github.com/melonproject/oyente. The combination of `assert()` in the contract to indicate intent and a code analyzer may get you part way to the sort of analysis you wanted.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand by transfer your self mean that the unknown contract can transfer ether from our contract and thereby generate the re-entrancy attack.

Comment: Just in case you're looking for a reference or detailed explanation. https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices/blob/master/docs/recommendations.md#avoid-state-changes-after-external-calls

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts written in solidity are usually tested using mocha. Though, any other library would work.

Here's what you could do to test your smart contract using JavaScript:

1. Compile the contract using solc.js
2. Deploy the contract on ganache.
3. Access the contracts functions using web3.
4. Write unit tests using mocha and assert.